# Django URL returns page not found. Django 1.9

Tags: django-templates, django-admin, django-views

Main site url conf:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

url(r'^admin/', include (admin.site.urls)),

url(r'^vibeapp/', include('vibeapp.urls'))
]
```

Vibe app url Conf:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from vibeapp import views

 urlpatterns = patterns['vibeapp.views',

 url(r'^$','index', name='index'),

 url(r'^homepage/$, homepage, name='index'),

 url(r'^vibeapp$', vibeapp, name='index'),

 ]
```

Vibeapp view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):

return HttpResponse("Hey!")
```

I am including my wsgi  in case this could be the problem:

import os

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I am currently working on Django 1.9 and have configured my main site url and the web app url and view. When I run the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/vibeapp it shows up as page not found.

Please find the code attached above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not correctly using the `patterns` function in the *Vibe app url Conf*. You are using it as a dictionary and it should be called as a function. Keep in mind that `patterns` is deprecated and it is going to disappear in Django 1.10. Take a look at the [documention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urls/#patterns).

Another issue is you should not repeat the `name=` of a url in the same group as you have done with 'index' in:

```
    ...
    url(r'^$','index', name='index'),
    url(r'^homepage/$, homepage, name='index'),
    url(r'^vibeapp$', vibeapp, name='index'),
    ...
```